# Unityで動画ファイルのzip圧縮率を上げたい

Tags: c#, unity3d

GZipStreamを使用してZip圧縮を行う処理を作成いたしました。

以下のコードを使用して端末内に保存した動画ファイル(mp4)を圧縮しているのですが、圧縮率が98～99%ほどで容量を小さくするといった目的を達成できません。

Unityで高圧縮ができるライブラリや、コードの修正点など教えていただければと思います。
よろしくお願い致します。

**環境:**
Unity 2018.4.22.f1

**作成したコード:**

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] src)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var ds = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true/*msは*/))
        {
            ds.Write(src, 0, src.Length);
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        byte[] comp = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(comp, 0, comp.Length);
        return comp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**MP4 自体が既に圧縮された動画形式** なので、ここからさらに ZIP 圧縮をかけようとしてもほとんど効果は無いと思います。

動画サイズを小さくしたいなら、不要な部分をトリミングしたり、解像度やビットレート等を変更して再エンコードが必要となりそうです。